# How do I get properties from object correctly?

Tags: typescript

Could you help me please? I try to transform object like this:

```
const initObj = {
    'foo-0-bar11': 'value1',
    'foo-0-bar12': 'value2',
    'foo-0-bar13': 'value3',

    'foo-1-bar21': 'value1',
    'foo-1-bar22': 'value2',
    'foo-1-bar23': 'value3',

    'foo-2-bar31': 'value1',
    'foo-2-bar32': 'value2',
    'foo-2-bar33': 'value3',
};
```

into array like this:

```
const resArr = [
        // contents of foo-0-*
        {
            bar11: value1,
            bar12: value2,
            bar13: value3
        },
        // contents of foo-1-*
        {
            bar21: value1,
            bar22: value2,
            bar23: value3
        },
        // contents of foo-2-*
        {
            bar31: value1,
            bar32: value2,
            bar33: value3
        }
];
```

I try to implement a transform function this way:

```
const getProperty = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K] => obj[key];
  

const transformData = (data: any) => {
      const dataObj = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, item) => {
      const [identifier, value] = item;

      const [, index, type] = identifier.split('-');

      if (!(index in acc)) {
          Object.defineProperty(acc, index, {value: {}});
      }
        
      const innerObj: object = getProperty(acc, index);
      Object.defineProperty(innerObj, type, {value});

      return acc;

      }, {});

      return Object.values(dataObj);
};
```

But I get this message from the compiler
`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.` and
the `index` is underlined at line `const innerObj: object = getProperty(acc, index);`

How do I implement this functionality correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.reduce` is somewhat verbose in JS, and a whole lot more verbose in TS due to the type required for the accumulator. In a situation like this, where the accumulator is always the same object, using `.reduce` arguably [isn't very appropriate anyway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) - easier to create the object ahead of time, typed properly, then just iterate over the data.

```
const transformData = (data: {[key: string]: string}) => {
    const acc: {
        [key: string]: {
            [key: string]: string;
        }
    } = {};
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      const [, index, type] = key.split('-');
      if (!acc[index]) {
          acc[index] = {};
      }
      acc[index][type] = value;
    });
    return Object.values(acc);
};
console.log(transformData(initObj))
```